# other meaning of "Welsh"

Tags: word-meaning

> When Morgan Williams comes in, he is wearing his good town coat. **He
>   looks Welsh and pugnacious**; it's clear he's heard the news. He stands
>   by Kat, staring down, temporarily out of words; till he says, ‘See!’
>   He makes a fist, and jerks it three times in the air. ‘That!’ he says.
>   ‘That's what he'd get. Walter. That's what he'd get. From me.’

(Wolf Hall by Hilary Mantel)

Why Morgan Williams look **Welsh**? Is it because he has heard the news and is so mad at what happened? Then, what is the meaning of "**Welsh**" here?

Comment: Morgan Williams is a Welsh name and he was Welsh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SUPPLEMENTAL** to Maulik V's answer:

Maulik V nails the general sense of the sentence: Morgan Williams has an outward appearance which conforms to the stereotyped image of a Welshman.

In the 16th century, when this novel is set, Englishmen attached a number of stereotypes to the Welsh: they're dirty, they're thievish, they're fond of cheese and leeks, they keep goats, they practise magic, they're obsessed with their lineage, and they're belligerent and overly quick to take personal offense. Belligerence is probably what the author (more properly, Thomas, through whose eyes we see this scene) has in mind: note that Morgan is characterized as "Welsh **and pugnacious**".

Answer (score 3):

When you get an 'avatar' of something popular, you become 'that'. In other words, if you become 'that', you show all the (typical?) characteristics of something/one.

> He looks Welsh and...

IMO, this means, at that time, he had all the characteristics of a typical Welsh (**maybe** wearing a good town coat is one of the features).

Something like --if [I am staring at french fries with a glass of soft drink and burger on table **and** if I am somewhat *fat*](http://marketplace.veer.com/stock-photo/Stereotypical-American-man-holding-a-FSP0143696), you may say...

> Maulik looked *American*

I haven't read Wolf Hall but it may mean that Mr. Williams showed all the characteristics of Welsh at that moment.

Comment: It seems possible to me that there is some stereotype of Welshmen that is being referenced here. I don't know what it would be, though.

Comment: That's what I said... :) @MrTheWalrus

Comment: I don't think your use of "looked lawyer" is correct. Looked like a lawyer would be correct. A functional example of what you're trying to illustrate would be "Maulik looked rich" or "Maulik looked American" or "Maulik looked Finnish"

Comment: @TechnikEmpire trust me, I first thought of giving an example of 'maulik looked American' but then thought to go with 'coat' which is in the original question. But American's example is better...changed!

Comment: Speaking English flawlessly, unfortunately, is not a trait many Americans have. Regardless, you can't "look" American because of how you speak English, you would "sound" American.

Comment: But the gesture of 'chewing gum' adds an American flavor to the character I guess. I cannot come up with an example which is culturally perfect and if I give an Indian example, many won't understand. You can help me getting a precise example for this, it's appreciated. @Catija

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotypes_of_Americans) are some possible stereotypes you could use.... and another [site](http://www.nationalstereotype.com/american-stereotypes/). :)

Comment: @TechnikEmpire well, I think the answer talks about 'stereotyping' what the OP is concerned about (irrespective of the 'facts' or personal view of how an American looks/behaves). I'm a non-native and cannot come up with culturally perfect example. If it's still down to you, I think only a native can correct this.

Comment: +1 But *Welsh* is ordinarily an adjective; it is used as a noun only in speaking of the entire *Welsh* people ("The Welsh have their own language"), not to denote an individual *Welshman*.